# What is the meaning of the follwing sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> His critics pointed out that until he addressed his problem,success at the highest level will continue to elude him.

Does this mean ' He was already a successful person at highest level' ?

Im not getting the meaning of "continue to elude him" right .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He is successful. Yet he still has the potential to greatly improve his craft. Some problem interferes with that.  Until that problem is addressed, he cannot achieve the ultimate success.  At this point, it still eludes him.

So no, it does not mean he was already successful at the highest level.  That is what is unobtainable until he overcomes what limits him.  It might be drug addiction, poor motivation, poor health -- any number of things could be holding him back.

Answer (score 1):

Elude means "to avoid" or "to escape." In more simple words, the sentence means that critics have said that "he will not be successful at the highest level until he fixes his problem."

We can assume he is already successful, but he's not as successful as he could be.